# Wordpress Woocommerce Custom Drop Down Issues

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, woocommerce, wordpress

I am trying to add a dynamic drop down select list on a variable product but the foreach loop is not working. The select box appears but it empty. Printing the array shows the proper info. I seem to be missing a state issue or something.

Desired Functionality: Each user has a unique list of characters that they need to be able to select on this variable product page. (Single product with several options.)

This code works perfectly on a theme template page. (childtheme)/testpage.php

It does not work on the custom woocommerce template file. Location: (childtheme)/woocommerce/variable/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
$clickedChar = $_GET['cc'];
$myChars = fyxt_myCharList ($fyxtAccountID); 
?>

<html>
<select name="char_list" required>
  <option value="">Select...</option>
</html>

<?php
    foreach($myChars as $clist){
        echo '<option value="'.$clist->idfyxt_character.'"'.(($clickedChar == $clist->idfyxt_character) ? ' selected="selected">' : '>' ).$clist->character_name.'</option>'; 
    }
?>
<html>
</select>
</html>
```

Like I said this code works perfectly on the testpage.php theme template page. But not on the woocommerce template page. It is not looping through the foreach.

I also had issues calling the Wordpress User ID and was forced to include

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

Specifically which is not normally needed on template pages. I suspect there is a similar issue here. Or at least a clue to what the issue is.

Thank you for your help and ideas!

Comment: 1. I presume the `<html>` elements are not in your actual code and are SO formatting gone wrong? 2. Can you share `fyxt_myCharList()` so the problem can be reproduced?

Comment: fyxt_myCharList() pulled an associative array of ID and Names. It was functioning fine. Not sure why it would work on theme template page but not woo template page. However the hook below solves that problem nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've guessed at a simplified version of your `fyxt_myCharList()` function. Using the `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` hook we can add some code to the variable product's page without needing to modify the add to cart template.

Also note the wonderful little function [`selected()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected) for using in dropdowns.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'so_34027544_custom_dropdown' );
function so_34027544_custom_dropdown(){
    global $product;
    if( is_product() && $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){

        $clickedChar = isset( $_GET['cc'] ) && in_array( $_GET['cc'], fyxt_myCharList() ) ? $_GET['cc'] : '';
        $myChars = fyxt_myCharList(); 
        ?>

        <select name="char_list" required>
          <option value=""><?php _e( 'Select...', 'my-textdomain' );?></option>

            <?php
                foreach($myChars as $clist){
                    echo '<option value="'.$clist.'"'. selected( $clickedChar, $clist, false ) . '>' .$clist.'</option>'; 
                }
            ?>

        </select>

        <?php
    }
}


function fyxt_myCharList(){
    return array( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' );
}
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! A little bit of tweaking and this seems to be working now. Thanks for the tip for selected as well. That is a nice litte function.

Comment: This helped me get the items on the variable product page. However, they are not being added to the cart. The cart shows the two static variables I assigned in the admin area but not the dynamic information that is entered into the two new fields. I have started this question to address that issue. Thanks for the help!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072637/wordpress-woocommerce-save-dynamic-frontend-attributes-to-product